# Antd form: passing dynamic id alongside form-values

Tags: reactjs, forms, antd

im working on a commenting system. Every ID has some comments. If I want to make a new comment, the ID has to be passed alongside the form-values.

ID is being rendered dynamically:

```
{data && data.formations.map(formation =>
            <Row>
                <Col span={2}>
                    <p>ID: {formation.id}</p>
                </Col>
                ...
```

Form has a Textarea, and the value is being passed automatically due the name prop in Form.Item.

```
<Form onFinish={onFinish}>
    <Form.Item name="comment">
        <TextArea rows={4} />
    </Form.Item>
    <Form.Item>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">Add comment</Button>
    </Form.Item>
</Form>
```

Idealy, I want the ID passed alongside the values in the following function OnFinish:

```
const onFinish = (values) *id somehwere here* => {
    console.log(values)
}
```

How to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You could solve this by adding an hidden field which holds the ID :

```
<Form onFinish={onFinish}>
    <Form.Item name="comment">
        <TextArea rows={4} />
    </Form.Item>
    <Form.Item name="id">
        <Input type="hidden" value={formation.id} />
    </Form.Item>
    <Form.Item>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">Add comment</Button>
    </Form.Item>
</Form>
```

Then in the onFinish callback you should get a new property `id` in the `values` object.

This is the common way to pass known/readonly values alongside form values (in the non SPA / synchronous web world, eg PHP).